# Discount price applied but not deducting from TAX summary

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, tax

Sorry about my broken english as I am not a native english speaker.

I am update Magento 1.9 website from 1.8, finishing, discount price not subtracted from one page checkout page tax.

Discounts apply PayPal and other pages, there is no problem.

Grand Total Excluding Tax   416,67

TAX             33,33

Grand Total Including Tax   450,00

Subtotal            450,00

Discount (discount35)       -157,50

Comment: Please clarify: Your tax percentage is 33,33% and you want to give a 35% discount? Should the **Grand Total Including Tax and Before Discount** in your example be 450,00? And should the **Grand Total Excluding Tax and After Discount** be 219,92?

Comment: Tax percentage not 33,33%. This tax price. I am lowered the discount rate and try:
Subtotal 1.000,00

Discount (discount10) -100,00 

Grand Total Excluding Tax 925,93

TAX 74,07 

Grand Total Including Tax 1.000,00

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Attaching the link to my Problem below: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107583/grand-total-not-updated-when-discount-code-is-applied Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

Copy app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml and paste it to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml. 
Then after [image]

Add

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me in Magento 1.9.1

Comment: cheers my firiend

Comment: are these images?

Comment: yes my friend :)

Comment: This fixed my problem with discount can you please explain why this error generate

Comment: Not working bro :(

Comment: @AsishHira If i apply shopping cart price rule, it will be applied on subtotal how to make it rule apply only on a product not subtotal?

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to tell exactly why your store isn't calculating tax properly when using discounts, but it is most likely caused by wrong settings in:

`System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings`

[image]

I have outlined the most important settings related to discounts in the screen shot above. Below you will find some explanation for those settings from page 607 of the Magento 1.9.1 User Guide, which you can download [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide).

> - In the **Apply Customer Tax** field, select whether tax is applied to the    original or discounted price.
> - In the **Apply Discount on Prices** field, select whether any discounts    applied include the tax or exclude it.
> - In the **Apply Tax On** field, select whether tax is applied to custom    prices or to original prices.

You can try different settings and see if this will lead to correct tax calculation. Make and keep a screen shot of your original settings prior to making any changes, in case you want to go back to where you started from.

To find out more about Magento Tax Settings click [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/tax-settings).

Comment: The store settings like this. I tried all the settings and can not result. Thank you for comment.