# grant total not reduced after applay cupon code in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, discount, grand-total

i have applayed a cupon code which have 100 rs rduction after apply this code i can see the discont as 100 but the grant total have no change please refer the picture

[image]

Comment: Please let me know the php version you are using in server?

Comment: please confirm so that i can help you thanks

Comment: check any other shopping cart rule overrding this rule priority.... also check configuration again ,  flush cache and try in private window once....

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa php 7.0.1

Comment: Ok now still  your r facing same problem?